# How to reference subclass that made a call on super?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance

Given the following classes:

```
class BaseImport

  private

    @number_of_errors = 0
    @number_of_records_added = 0

    def import_from_this_database(params={})
      # Import Log contains the following attributes:
      # class_name, method_name, number_of_records_added, number_of_errors, last_date_checked, last_modified_date
      ImportLog.create(params)
    end
end

class MyObjectImport < BaseImport
  private
    def import_from_this_database()
      # Do alot of import processing

      if record.valid?
        record.save
        @number_of_records_added += 1
      else
        @number_of_errors += 1
      end

      super # Call the BaseImport class' method to Log the Import.
    end
end
```

Is it possible to eliminate the need of passing the params object to super and just refer to the subclasses' class_name, and method_name that called super?

Comment: `@number_of_errors` in `BaseImport` is a class instance variable. In `MyObjectImport` you are are referencing an instance variable with the same name. Do you mean the latter to be  `self.class.instance_variable_set(:@number_of_records_added,
      self.class.instance_variable_get(:@number_of_records_added)+1)`? Same for `@number_of_errors`, of course.

Comment: Probably better to create accessors for the class instance variables (e.g., `class BaseImport; singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, :number_of_records_added); end` (`BaseImport.methods(false) #=> [:number_of_records_added, :number_of_records_added=]` ). Then in the instance_method `record_valid?`, you could write `self.class.number_of_records_added = self.class.number_of_records_added + 1